# How can I access the values of my view's dropdown list in my controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html-select

How can I access the values of my view's dropdown list in my controller?

```
var typeList = from e in db.Rubrics where e.DepartmentID == 2 select e;
var selectedRubrics = typeList.Select(r => r.Category);
IList <String> rubricsList = selectedRubrics.ToList();
IList<SelectListItem> iliSLI = new List<SelectListItem>(); 
SelectListItem selectedrubrics = new SelectListItem();
selectedrubrics.Text = "Choose a category";
selectedrubrics.Value = "1";
selectedrubrics.Selected = true;
iliSLI.Add(selectedrubrics);
for(int i = 0;i<rubricsList.Count();++i)
{
    iliSLI.Add(new SelectListItem() {
        Text = rubricsList[i], Value = i.ToString(), Selected = false });
}
ViewData["categories"] = iliSLI;
```

In my view this works fine showing the dropdown values:

```
@Html.DropDownList("categories")
```

Then in my controller I am using `FormCollection` like this:

```
String[] AllGradeCategories = frmcol["categories"].Split(',');
```

When I put a breakpoint here, I get an array of 1’s in  *AllGradeCategories*. What am I doing wrong?

MORE:
Here’s my begin form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("History", "Attendance",
    new {courseID = HttpContext.Current.Session ["sCourseID"] },
    FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "formName", @name = "formName" }))
    {
        <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.HomeworkGrade, new { Value = "7" }) 
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => item.HomeworkGrade)
        </td>
        <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.attendanceCode, new { Value = "1" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Enrollments.FirstOrDefault().attendanceCode)
        </td>  
        <td>  
        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.classDays)
        </td>
        <td>
        @Html.DropDownList("categories")
        </td>
    }
```

My controller signature:

```
  public ActionResult ClassAttendance(InstructorIndexData viewModel, int id, FormCollection frmcol, int rows, String sTeacher, DateTime? date = null)
```

EDITED 2
Tried this but although it seems to get posted, the I still don’t get the values of the list in the hidden field or the categories parameter.

```
             @Html.Hidden("dropdownselected1");
   @Html.DropDownList("categories",ViewBag.categories as SelectList, new { onchange = "changed" })

                 </td>


  $(function () {


    $("#dropdownselected1").val($("#categories").val());

  });
```

Comment: please share more of your view (esp form) and your action method signature. we can straighten this out.

Comment: I added to my original post.

Comment: this helps. I dont see a definition for your model, how it sent to view, or how it is bound to view

Comment: I send it to the view in ViewData like this:ViewData["categories"] = iliSLI;

Comment: I see that. You are determined to do away with the M in MVC. You can accomplish this, but it will be an ongoing head ache. Better to learn how to send models to the View and back to your Controller.

Comment: I've used the model to send other dropdown lists and you're right it is easier.  In this case my user will be able to edit the values that appear in the list.  It's easier to grab the data right from the form if I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a ViewModel to handle just the drowdown list with an associated partial view.  Then in the controller I accessed the values of the list using FormCollection().

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to access the selected value from the dropdown list, use a hidden field and repopulate that field on onChange() javascript event of the dropdown list.

```
but you can use normal 
@Html.Hidden("dropdownselected1");


@Html.DropDownList("categories",new { onchange ="changed();"}

function changed()
{
   $("#hiddenfieldid").val($("#dropdownlistid").val());

}
```

should do.

Comment: My dropdown list is in ViewData not directly tied into the model so no hidden field for it.

Comment: Tried:  @Html.DropDownList("categories",new {onchange="changed();"})...got error message that there is no definition for DropDownList.

Comment: Sorry, make sure u have Jquery plugged in to the page, or use normal document.getelementbyid("xyz").value